# Reset Mouse First Click When Zooming in MSCharts

Tags: c#, mouse, zooming, reset, mschart

I am using the MSCharts in my winform to show some charts.
I have the charts set so the user can zoom:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
```

I also use the MouseDown event and the Call Hit Test Method to drill down in the chart and show other chart info. :

```
private void chart1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  //***** Call Hit Test Method
  HitTestResult result = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
  if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint || result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPointLabel)
   {
   //*************************Goes into the Pie Chart - Dept
      int z = result.PointIndex;
      result.Series.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
      DateTime x = DateTime.FromOADate(result.Series.Points[z].XValue);
      string name = result.Series.Name.ToString();
      name = name + "(" + x.ToShortDateString() + ")";
      if (funChartExists(name) == false)
      {       
         subMakeNewPieSeries(result.Series.Name.ToString(), x, name);
      }
      chart1.ChartAreas["Pie"].Visible = true;
      chart1.ChartAreas["Task"].Visible = false;
      chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].Visible = false;
      chart1.Series[name].Enabled = true;
      chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = false;
      chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].RecalculateAxesScale();
   }
   chart1.Invalidate();
}
```

I also have a button that resets the charts to the first view:

```
private void cmbReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.ChartAreas["Pie"].Visible = false;
    chart1.ChartAreas["Task"].Visible = false;
    chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].Visible = true;
    chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
    for (int x = 0; x < chart1.Series.Count; x++)
    {
        if (chart1.Series[x].ChartArea == "Pie" || chart1.Series[x].ChartArea == "Task")
        {
            chart1.Series[x].Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].RecalculateAxesScale();
    chart1.Invalidate();        
}
```

My problem is when I go back to the main chart (using the reset button), The chart is retaining that mouse click from the first drill down and is waiting for the second click (Or Mouse Up) to zoom in. So when you move the mouse it is draging a dark gray backgound selection waiting for that second zoom point.

Is there a way to reset the mouse selection zoom values, or turn it off when I do my Hit Test, then turn it back on after the reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when should we use mouse down and when should we use mouse up?

Mouse down should be used when the operation is part of a sequence that beings with the button going down and ends with the button coming up.

Mouse up should be used when the operation is of a single nature (a 'click').

Should you be using down or up? Does up function correctly and does it solve your problem?

As a general rule of thumb (which is sometimes neglected by naive programmers), a mouse down + mouse move + mouse up operation has the following form:

```
MouseDown
    Capture the mouse

MouseMove
    If MouseIsCaptured
        Perform move operation

MouseUp
    If MouseIsCaptured
        Release capture and finalize the operation
```

If the chart control follows this procedure, your solution might be as simple as releasing the mouse capture yourself. This should be `chartControlInstance.Capture = false`.

Comment: I moved the Hit Test Method to the Mouse Up Event and that seemed to work for what I wanted. It see that the MouseUp location is in the same place as the mouse down and does not zoom, and then gets the mouse location for the drill down to the other charts.  I tried the chartControlInstance.Capture = false, but that did not seem to do anyting for my zooming problem.

Comment: @JohnMamberg I noticed that your MouseDown method is an event handler. To interrupt the down+move+up operation of the chart control, you could try deriving from it in your own class, then use the OnMouseDown override instead of the event. That will allow you to call the base class implementation first, then try releasing mouse capture.